# How do I apply `NOW()` as datetime column value in Kotlin Exposed?

Tags: kotlin-exposed

In PostgreSQL I have a table with a column of the [`timestamp` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html). I *hope* this maps to a [Kotlin Exposed data type](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DataTypes) of `datetime` (docs are unclear, but that's another question).

My question now is: how do I update/insert a value with the SQL literal `NOW()`, so that the timestamp is set to the current timestamp by the database server?

I'm currently trying to apply this in the Exposed DSL API like this:

```
object MyTable : Table() {
    val col1: Column<String> = varchar("col1", 100).primaryKey()
    val last_update: Column<DateTime?> = datetime("last_update").nullable()
}

MyTable.update ({ MyTable.col1 eq "abcd1234" }) {
    // How do I put a literal 'NOW()' here?
    it[MyTable.last_update] = ...
}
```

I found a way to declare a custom Expression in the Exposed source code, like this:

```
val nowExpression = object : Expression<DateTime>() {
    override fun toSQL(queryBuilder: QueryBuilder) = "NOW()"
}
```

But how do I apply that in my update/insert statement?

Kotlin unit tests I found:

- Use Kotlin-side of `DateTime.now()` (not what I want), or
- Use a column default value of now, then omitting the column value in the insert. This is where I found the literal `NOW()` expression. However, I want to keep my default to NULL on that column.

I did not find a unit test to apply a custom expression in a DSL insert/update, but perhaps I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

There is `update` function on Insert/Update statements which accepts `Expression`.

```
MyTable.update ({ MyTable.col1 eq "abcd1234" }) { 
  it.update(MyTable.last_update, nowExpression)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the original approach seems not to work any longer. 1) `Expression.toSql()` was deprecated, and 2) `toString()` must be used, but toString() is final and cannot be overridden. I guess I have to file a new issue.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you have.
Just update your nowExpression declaration to:
`override fun toQueryBuilder(queryBuilder: QueryBuilder) = queryBuilder {
                +"NOW()"
            }`